# Can I safely plug something that draws 6 amps into the cigar lighter (power port) in my Piper Archer lll?

Tags: safety, electrical-system

Can I safely plug something that draws 6 amps into the cigar lighter (power port) in my Piper Archer lll ?

Comment: What's the breaker rating?

Comment: I wish I could find it. If it's in the POH, I don't see it.  Sent a note to my mechanic, hoping to get some info.

Comment: It depend of what you are trying to plug. If this is something not designed to withstand flight condition (pressure variation, acceleration,...), it is not safe to bring it in flight, plugged or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely plug in a 6A load. Possibly a circuit breaker will pop out after some time. That depends on the rating of the circuit breaker serving the outlet and if there are any other loads on that circuit breaker. But it is completely safe to try it.

Comment: If you're going to "just try it", you may want to do so while taxiing for a while. Better that something unexpected go "pop" while still on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Cigar lighters usually have a 10amp breaker and wiring to match, but the sockets themselves are pretty poor quality and only designed to be active for 30 seconds or so. They can get pretty hot when used for any length of time, such as an air-bed inflator or tyre pump, even when the load is well below the breaker's limit.

If your use is at all critical, I'd be tempted to replace it with a bulkhead-mounted XT60 or similar connector.